# sqlite database design

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables

```
Table 1: PlantName (primary key)

Table 2: (primary key(Id + PlantName)), foreign key(PlantName) references Table1(PlantName)

Table 3: (primary key(Id + PlantName)), foreign key(id) references Table2(id)

When I insert data into these tables

Table1: Ark1
Ark2
Ark3

Table 2:
1,Ark1
2,Ark1
3, Ark1
1, Ark2
2, Ark2
1, B1
2, B2

Table 3:
1,Ark1
2,Ark2
```

At this insertion in Table3 it has a problem with Foreign key.

Please suggest

Thank you

Sun

Answer (score 1):

B1 and B2 do not exist in table 1, which causes the foreign key violation.

Comment: sorry, please see the edit. Fkey violation is caused during insertion for Table 3.